# Can't install PyBluez2 on Raspbian

Tags: python, bluetooth, pip

Title - I can't install `pybluez2`:

```
bluetooth/linux/bluez/btmodule.c:20:10: fatal error: btmodule.h: No such file or directory      
20 | #include "btmodule.h"
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

BlueZ is installed:

```
pi@rpi:~ $ bluetoothctl -v
bluetoothctl: 5.55
```

I already installed the packages `libbluetooth-dev` and `python3-dev` like it's written everywhere. Still no success.
I found the missing file in this location: `/usr/include/bluetooth/bluetooth.h`

I'm using a RPI 3 with `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`.

How do I install pybluez2?

Comment: Are you looking for `python3-bluez`? `sudo apt install python3-bluez`

Comment: Looking at https://www.piwheels.org/project/pybluez2/ it would appear that it was version 0.42 that last built successfully on RPi Bullseye. What version are you trying to install? Use `pip install pybluez==0.42` to try with that version.

Comment: @Dougie Thanks that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Python3 version of BlueZ.

`sudo apt install python3-bluez`